# Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.16: how to get the sorting distance?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

When you try to sort by distance in ES, the result usually contains the distance between matches and your search location:

```
  "hits": {
"total": 3,
"max_score": null,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "circle",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "7",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "id": 7,
      "coordinates": {
        "lon": 112.548443,
        "lat": 37.780269
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      116.39283058047849
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "circle",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "5",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "id": 5,
      "coordinates": {
        "lon": 112.55061,
        "lat": 37.779145
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      231.9203763747634
    ]
  }
]
```

}
The sorting distance is contained in `sort` field.
How do I get sorting distance in Spring Date Elasticsearch 2.1.16, with elasticsearchTemplate?

Here is my code for query:  `Page<CircleES> resultPage = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, CircleES.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this information in version 2.1.16 you need to use the method

```
queryForPage(SearchQuery query, Class<T> clazz, SearchResultMapper mapper)
```

and provide a custom `SearchResultMapper` which parses the desired information from the returned data.

Btw, 2.1.16 was released on October 15th, 2018 and is out of support.